# Stereo input to mono connector

Tags: mixing, mixer

If I have this mixer

[image: 1]

and I connect a stereo input by using a mini-jack to 2 TRS connectors to 2 different mono line channels and keeping the pan to 12 o'clock, is it good for both left and right output to receive both left and right input signal?

I'm doing this for other reasons that I'm not writing. I would like to know if it's safe for a speaker to receive bot left and right signals of a song in the input.

Answer (score 1):

This will cause absolutely no problems. You could pan each of the signals wherever you want and it will not cause issues, so experiment with them to determine what sounds best to you.

Answer (score 0):

In short no it will not ***harm*** the mixer or speaker

**BUT**

Using a “mini” TRS stereo signal to TRS into the first four channels will result in a very bad output because of the [differential amplifier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier).
Putting them into the other channels will result in a loss of the right channel. It’s better to use mono to mono, stereo to stereo, and balanced to balanced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so if I use the stereo input in the stereo channel and fed the sub by using the aux port didn't I get the same result as I send the stereo channel to the same aux "mono" link?

Comment: @stefy97100 I’m not sure exactly what you are asking but maybe if you reword it I can understand. If you use TRS cables into an unbalanced input then you lose one side and if you use stereo TRS into a balanced input you get polarity issues. You should use 3.5mm to RCA or 3.5mm to 1/4” TS breakout cable.

Comment: I try to rephrase it. I'm connecting an audio source (music) by using 3.5mm to 1/4” TS cable (I was incorrect in the main post). The 1/4" connectors are going into the first 2 mono channels (because I want gain control and mid eq). 
Do I get a "bad output" If I set both channel's pan to 12 o'clock OR if I send both channel to the same aux port?

Comment: @stefy97100 No, in that case Rory’s answer is correct. The pan only has to do with the left and right outputs, or headphones. If you pan to the right then nothing will come out of a speaker plugged into the left output that is all.

Comment: But If set both left and right channels' pan to 12 o'clock doesn't I get 2 overlapping signals in both left and right output? Is it a problem?
Ps. sorry if I keep asking but I would like to be sure :)

Comment: @stefy97100 You will have the sum of both channels going to the speaker. It is no problem and it is what the mixer is made to do and the speaker doesn’t know the difference.